# Was Sekai in School Days anime really pregnant?

Tags: school-days

In the final episode of *School Days* anime, Sekai said that she was pregnant. Her behavior seemed like she was telling the truth.

However, when Kotonoha offered Sekai to consult at the hospital, she refused to go. This made Kotonoha suspect that Sekai was lying. And when Kotonoha stabbed and dissected Sekai, Kotonoha confirmed her suspicion.

But even before her death, Sekai stated clearly that she was pregnant, though she didn't have to lie to Kotonoha anymore as Makoto was already dead.

So was Sekai really pregnant or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not definite, and you'll hear differing opinions based on who's talking about it:

**She was pregnant:**

- She had morning sickness
- Kotonaha's attempt at searching inside Sekai is of course fruitless, as the baby would not have had enough time to develop. Maybe after several weeks something would be visible. Also it's a very crude way of doing it, so it's not surprising she wouldnt see anything, not being a trained professional
- She didn't want to go to the hospital understandably, it would be a frightening and stressful experience.
- She had no motive, she was clearly worried by the experience.

**She was not pregnant:**

- Morning sickness started occuring too early
- [There have been several instances of fake pregnancies,](http://www.webmd.com/baby/guide/false-pregnancy-pseudocyesis) where the body emulates all the symptoms of pregnancy (sickness, missed periods, etc) because of stress / belief that they are pregnant
- She was scared that her lie would be revealed if she went to the doctor
- Her motive could have been that a baby would tie Makoto strongly to her.

[Sekai Fandom page](http://overflow.fandom.com/wiki/Sekai_Saionji)

I doubt you'll find a conclusive answer, as many posts out there have already made up their mind. But one thing I think we can gather is at least **she thought she was pregnant**, regardless of if she was or not.

Comment: Basically Sekai may or may not have been mistaken, but Sekai wasn't lying?

Answer (score 5):

**She's not Pregnant**

And here's the reasons why.

***Side notes before starting reading at these proofs.*** 
*Me myself have experienced depression before and at one time It was to the point where I felt nauseous and almost to the point of throwing up.*

- About her morning sicknesses, since Sekai herself at the time was at an down state, thinking of her best friend Setsuna judging herself might have triggered this occurrence.
  There's clearly something wrong with Sekai as the way how possesive of Makoto she's been acting as, so It's probably just her delusions of having one taking in place.
- Sekai never had the proof of her actually being pregnant, as she herself have never used an pregnancy tester before on her own, before even telling Makoto that she's pregnant.
- According to the Wiki, it's been stated that Kotonoha was an educated young lady, so she's probably informed about where the baby *exactly* is at.
- She's having early morning sicknesses.
- The specific week of when morning sicknesses ends is at the 10th week of an baby's development.  The embryo would be the size of an slightly smaller lime.
- Looking at how the anime is progressing, and how quickly the announcement of her pregnancy before Makoto then shortly after Sekai's death, is quite a bit tad too fast for an 2month development of the embryo.
- She's showing signs of aggression when asked if she had proofs of pregnancy by Docters before.

So when Kotonoha cutted open Sekai's womb, since according to the speed of development, the embryo itself would be visible to the naked eye.
The way how Sekai ended up as an character, looking at her character development, it was apparent that she's very possessive of Makoto even till the end.
So

---

In conclusion, Sekai was lying all along.

Comment: Jia Hui Xu do you really mean lying instead of made a mistake?